# How to access data from ozone using spark?

Tags: apache-spark, ozone

How to access data from ozone using **spark-shell/spark-submit**

Answer (score 0):

In the following community article, i have created by step by step how to create a ozone volume and buckets. After that how we can access ozone data using spark-shell.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-Ozone-Integration-in-CDP/ta-p/323132